# Function inputs and outputs in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I'm building some relatively simple functions in PROLOG that take one input and one output. For simplicity, something like

```
func(List, Item, [Item | List]).
```

Now, I've got code that will call several of these functions in a row and pass the result on. The issue is that I have to keep creating new variable names for all of the outputs.

```
someOtherFunc(List, Item) :-
   func(List, Item, Output1),
   doSomething(Output1).
```

The issue here is that I actually have several `func` and several `doSomething` and would really appreciate not having to bind an `Output1` variable explicitly. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You might be able to use DCGs to hide arguments, but I'm not really sure. After reading your question several times I still don't understand what exactly do you want...

Comment: They are not functions, they are predicates. Then, if a predicate of three arguments takes one input and yields one output, then one of the arguments is superfluous. Your `func` predicate is a no-op, so you might want to come up with a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you're asking, but first of all please note that those are **not** functions, but predicates. This is a totally different programming paradigm. Variables are not "boxes" where you put in and out some data: they're closer to the mathematical meaning of variable, since once you bind them to some constraints on their values it's forever.

To go back to your question, the answer is no, you can't avoid binding some Output1 like that. Sometimes you can put in an underscore to tell prolog you just don't care about that value, but doing so you lose the ability to make use of that particular value. In your example you would like to do something like this (in a imperative pseudocode):

```
var list = ..., item = ...;
doSomething(func(list, item));
```

There's no other way in prolog as far as I know, you just have to use intermediate variables as you did. The only improvement I can suggest, is to choose very carefully predicates and variables names.

Answer (score 0):

```
func1(Input1, Input2) :-
   func2(Input1, Input2, Output1),
   useFun(Output1, Output2).
/* Output2 the result I obtain from the function useFun */
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your code snippet to make your solution easier understandable.